# Not being able to click on visible element in a input datepicker field with selenium webdriver 3

Tags: webdriver, selenium3

In the Expedia.com, on flights section, there're two inputs (departing and returning) for handle dates.

I'm not being able to get the right element so that I can click and sendKeys to it. I've tried many types and only using the place holder it works for returning input, but not for departing.

I'm using this: @FindBy (xpath = "//input[@placeholder='City or airport']") but it's clicking on the returning instead of departing.

So, what can I put in this locator so that I can get the right one? I've tried also with index [1] or [2] but didn't worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to insert the Departing date the input can be selected by `#flight-departing-flp`
Flight returning input element can be selected by `#flight-returning-flp`
Flying from airport field can be selected `//input[@data-airport_code_element="flight-origin-flp-airport_code"]` etc.

Comment: It's not working for me. I've already tried with those options and I'm getting the classic: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: @FindBy(css="#flight-departing-flp")
  WebElement departureDate;   It's not working. All the obvious locators I've already tried with no success.

Comment: I have this set of data, but not able to find locators with none of them: <input id="flight-departing-hp-flight" class="text datepicker-trigger-input gcw-start-date gcw-update-date-range gcw-storeable gcw-required gcw-valid-date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" data-gcw-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" autocomplete="off" data-min-range-length="0" data-gcw-storeable-name="gcw-start-date" data-gcw-field-type="departing date" name="starDate" aria-invalid="true" aria-label="
          Departing
        expanded. Enter a date or choose one from the table below. Showing Mar 2018 Apr 2018">

Comment: The selectors I wrote are definitely correct. What are you trying to do with these elements? These are inputs, not regular text areas so you can't sendKeys to these elements

Comment: I'm trying to click on it so that I can view and then start to work with the elements in the datepicker. It's not clicking and throwing the error I've mentioned, even with those obvious selectors.

Comment: Maybe you need to switch into the form first? All these elements inside form id = gcw-packages-form-hp-package

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Let me try doing it myself first :)

Comment: Works perfect!
I used the simplest code:

public class expedia {
    String homePageUrl = "https://www.expedia.com/";
    String departingID = "package-departing-hp-package";


    public void tryThis(WebDriver driver)
    //This method performs Twitter login with existing user
    {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        driver.get(homePageUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id(departingID)).click();
    }
}

Comment: And it works perfect. I can present you a screenshot presenting a departing date data selecting window opened.

Comment: what is the #version of chromedriver or gecko have you used?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"package-departing-hp-package"}
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)

Comment: Your issue is not about the chromedriver version. I have a chromedriver I downloaded in last December. And your problem, I guess, not about the selector. I can't see your code from here, but it works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, well, I give up. It's really weird. Maybe I have to study more. But for now I give up. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I'm sorry we could not really find the cause of your problem :(
"Thanks" from you could be receiving and up-voting of my answer :)